# FastApi: Celery Worker not executing tasks and tasks stay in Unack

Tags: python, mongodb, rabbitmq, celery

I wrote myself a test app to get the hang of Celery and RabbitMQ.
All my messages seem stuck in the "Unack" state on RabbitMQ...
The task is supposed to be executed by a worker and the result must be stored in my local MongoDb (which I am not sure if it is set up correctly sofar), I also want all the messages to move through a specific queue named "tasks". I must be able to call the "check_task_status" endpoint and after about 20 seconds after calling the "execute_task" the "check_task_status" endpoint still has an output of "PENDING". I can not put my finger on the issue.

I started up my worker with:

```
celery -A tasks worker -Q tasks --loglevel=INFO
```

Quick note: So initially I left my worker and there were not any errors but after waiting a while (keeping my worker running),  I got a new "timeout" error message in the terminal where the worker was running. Here is my terminal output:

```
[2023-08-02 09:21:53,043: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2023-08-02 09:21:53,073: INFO/MainProcess] celery@DESKTOP-490VADQ ready.
[2023-08-02 09:22:15,655: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.sample_task[9c586484-102d-47a7-859a-693026f5ed29] received
[2023-08-02 09:22:16,612: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-9] child process 5936 calling self.run()
[2023-08-02 09:22:16,621: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-10] child process 29216 calling self.run()
[2023-08-02 09:22:16,636: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-11] child process 10352 calling self.run()
[2023-08-02 09:22:17,435: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-12] child process 10776 calling self.run()
[2023-08-02 09:22:18,235: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-13] child process 14540 calling self.run()
[2023-08-02 09:29:50,785: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.sample_task[7451e7e0-3a57-4e3b-9481-7ef4895ab1b4] received
[2023-08-02 09:50:52,381: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.sample_task[2b54a897-b59b-4268-b9da-f7ad85f022ef] received
[2023-08-02 09:51:34,184: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.sample_task[b265be88-ff2d-4865-884a-5b0bc5e2b58b] received
[2023-08-02 09:52:15,686: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: PreconditionFailed(406, 'PRECONDITION_FAILED - delivery acknowledgement on channel 1 timed out. Timeout value used: 1800000 ms. This timeout value can be configured, see consumers doc guide to learn more', (0, 0), '')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Emile\Desktop\Projects\emile-test-2\.venv\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\worker.py", line 202, in start
    self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "C:\Users\Emile\Desktop\Projects\emile-test-2\.venv\lib\site-packages\celery\bootsteps.py", line 116, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "C:\Users\Emile\Desktop\Projects\emile-test-2\.venv\lib\site-packages\celery\bootsteps.py", line 365, in start
    return self.obj.start()
  File "C:\Users\Emile\Desktop\Projects\emile-test-2\.venv\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer\consumer.py", line 336, in start
    blueprint.start(self)
  File "C:\Users\Emile\Desktop\Projects\emile-test-2\.venv\lib\site-packages\celery\bootsteps.py", line 116, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "C:\Users\Emile\Desktop\Projects\emile-test-2\.venv\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer\consumer.py", line 726, in start
    c.loop(*c.loop_args())
  File "C:\Users\Emile\Desktop\Projects\emile-test-2\.venv\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\loops.py", line 130, in 
synloop
    connection.drain_events(timeout=2.0)
  File "C:\Users\Emile\Desktop\Projects\emile-test-2\.venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\connection.py", line 341, in drain_events
    return self.transport.drain_events(self.connection, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Emile\Desktop\Projects\emile-test-2\.venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\transport\pyamqp.py", line 171, 
in drain_events
    return connection.drain_events(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Emile\Desktop\Projects\emile-test-2\.venv\lib\site-packages\amqp\connection.py", line 525, in drain_events
    while not self.blocking_read(timeout):
  File "C:\Users\Emile\Desktop\Projects\emile-test-2\.venv\lib\site-packages\amqp\connection.py", line 531, in blocking_read
    return self.on_inbound_frame(frame)
  File "C:\Users\Emile\Desktop\Projects\emile-test-2\.venv\lib\site-packages\amqp\method_framing.py", line 53, in on_frame
    callback(channel, method_sig, buf, None)
  File "C:\Users\Emile\Desktop\Projects\emile-test-2\.venv\lib\site-packages\amqp\connection.py", line 537, in on_inbound_method
    return self.channels[channel_id].dispatch_method(
  File "C:\Users\Emile\Desktop\Projects\emile-test-2\.venv\lib\site-packages\amqp\abstract_channel.py", line 156, in dispatch_method
    listener(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Emile\Desktop\Projects\emile-test-2\.venv\lib\site-packages\amqp\channel.py", line 293, in _on_close
    raise error_for_code(
amqp.exceptions.PreconditionFailed: (0, 0): (406) PRECONDITION_FAILED - delivery acknowledgement on channel 1 timed out. Timeout value used: 1800000 ms. This timeout value can be configured, see consumers doc guide to learn more
```

Here is my code in the python project:

main.py:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from tasks import sample_task, celery

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/test")
def execute_task():
    task = sample_task.apply_async(queue='tasks')  # Send the task to the worker
    return {'task_id': task.id}

@app.get('/check_task_status/{task_id}')
def check_task_status(task_id: str):
    task_result = celery.AsyncResult(task_id)
    if task_result.state == 'PENDING':
        status = 'Task is pending'
    elif task_result.state == 'SUCCESS':
        status = 'Task completed successfully'
    elif task_result.state == 'FAILURE':
        status = 'Task failed'
    else:
        status = 'Task is in progress'
    return {'task_id': task_id, 'status': status}
```

tasks.py:

```
from celery import Celery
import time

celery = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//', backend='rpc://')
celery.config_from_object('celeryconfig')

@celery.task(queue='tasks', max_retries=5, retry_backoff=True, retry_backoff_max=1)
def sample_task():
    for i in range(4):
        time.sleep(5)
    print("Task Completed")
```

cerleryconfig.py:

```
broker_url = 'pyamqp://'
result_backend = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/'
imports = ('tasks')
mongodb_backend_settings = {
    'database': 'capetown',
    'taskmeta_collection': 'tasks-info',
}
task_serializer = 'json'
result_serializer = 'json'
accept_content = ['json']
task_routes = {
    'tasks.add': 'low-priority',
}
```

Any help would be kindly appreciated.
Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Your celery task `sample_task` is not explicitly defined in your `task_routes` setting so it is going to the default celery queue (which is named `celery`). You've told your worker to only read from the `tasks` queue.

You could launch your celery worker with:
`celery -A tasks worker -Q tasks,celery --loglevel=INFO`

or rename your default task queue to "tasks" in celeryconfig.py

```
task_default_queue = 'tasks'
```